# How to determine if the input to a function is integer in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing code to take an input (an integer), interpret the input as a year, and return the century. The code works fine except for input like `cent = centuries ([ 1 2])`. In this case it is supposed to return the empty string but it is returning the first century. I've used `~isinteger` and `~isscalar` and `y<1` and the like, but it's still returning a value. Please, what can I do here?

```
{
    function cent = centuries (y)
if margin >1
    cent = [];
return
if y >0 && y<= 100
    cent = 'I';
    elseif y> 100 && y <= 200
    cent = 'II'; 
    elseif y> 200 && y <= 300
    cent =  'III' ; 
    elseif y> 300 && y <= 400
    cent = 'IV' ; 
    elseif y> 400 && y <= 500
    cent = 'V' ; 
    elseif y> 500 && y <= 600
    cent = 'VI' ; 
    elseif y> 600 && y <= 700
    cent ='VII'; 
    elseif y> 700 && y <= 800
    cent = 'VIII' ; 
    elseif y> 800 && y <= 900
    cent ='IX' ; 
    elseif y> 900 && y <= 1000
    cent ='X' ; 
    elseif y> 1000 && y <= 1100
    cent ='XI' ; 
    elseif y> 1100 && y <= 1200
    cent = 'XII'; 
    elseif y> 1200 && y <= 1300
    cent ='XIII' ; 
    elseif y> 1300 && y <= 1400
    cent ='XIV' ; 
    elseif y> 1400 && y <= 1500
    cent ='XV'; 
    elseif y> 1500 && y <= 1600
    cent ='XVI' ; 
    elseif y> 1600 && y <= 1700
    cent ='XVII' ; 
    elseif y> 1700 && y <= 1800
    cent ='XVIII' ; 
    elseif y> 1800 && y <= 1900
    cent ='XIX'; 
    elseif y> 1900 && y <= 2000
    cent ='XX' ; 
    elseif y> 2000 && y <= 2100
    cent ='XXI' ; 
    elseif y> 2100 && y <= 2200
    cent ='XXII' ; 
    elseif y> 2200 && y <= 2300
    cent ='XXIII' ; 
    elseif y> 2300 && y <= 2400
    cent ='XXIV' ; 
    elseif y> 2400 && y <= 2500
    cent ='XXV' ; 
    elseif y> 2500 && y <= 2600
    cent ='XXVI' ; 
    elseif y> 2600 && y <= 2700
    cent ='XXVII' ; 
    elseif y> 2700 && y <= 2800
    cent ='XXVIII' ; 
    elseif y> 2800 && y <= 2900
    cent ='XXIX' ; 
    elseif y> 2900 && y <= 3000
    cent ='XXX'; 
else cent =''.';
end 
}
```

---

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbf9W.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2GB9.png)

please find attached the question and the code i wrote , I've used your suggestion but its not retuning an output for a non integer 
thanks

Comment: Could you please post the function signature as well, if not the code? Btw, `isscalar` should work!

Comment: The default data type is a double precision float. The only way to guarantee an integer is to cast the input as one of MATLAB's integer types.

Comment: This problem is from the Coursera "Introduction to Programming with MATLAB" by Vanderbilt University, isn't it? :D

Comment: @crazyGamer, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just need both of `isinteger( input )` and `isscalar( input )` together. it is also good to check if input is positive.

**Note:** if you are interested in integers which may be of type double, like 1.0, then you can use:

`mod( input, 1 ) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a strict check, you can use `nargin` (the number of input arguments) to check the number of inputs along with type checks:

```
function c = century(yr)
    if nargin == 1 && isscalar(yr) && ceil(yr) == yr && yr > 0
      % compute and return century value
    else
      c = [] % Or whatever the fail return value should be
    end
end
```

Note that I have used `ceil(yr) == yr` to check for integer values, even if it is stored in a double, as `issinteger` only accepts the argument if it is of type int and its related types. [Ref: [`isinteger`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isinteger.html)]. You can change that as per requirement.

---

#### Edit:

The complete function using the code you have provided: (It seems to work as required. Please check if you made the correct changes as per my suggestions.)

```
function cent = centuries (y)
    if nargin == 1 && isscalar(y) && ceil(y) == y && y > 0
        if y >0 && y<= 100
        cent = 'I';
        elseif y> 100 && y <= 200
        cent = 'II'; 
        elseif y> 200 && y <= 300
        cent =  'III' ; 
        elseif y> 300 && y <= 400
        cent = 'IV' ; 
        elseif y> 400 && y <= 500
        cent = 'V' ; 
        elseif y> 500 && y <= 600
        cent = 'VI' ; 
        elseif y> 600 && y <= 700
        cent ='VII'; 
        elseif y> 700 && y <= 800
        cent = 'VIII' ; 
        elseif y> 800 && y <= 900
        cent ='IX' ; 
        elseif y> 900 && y <= 1000
        cent ='X' ; 
        elseif y> 1000 && y <= 1100
        cent ='XI' ; 
        elseif y> 1100 && y <= 1200
        cent = 'XII'; 
        elseif y> 1200 && y <= 1300
        cent ='XIII' ; 
        elseif y> 1300 && y <= 1400
        cent ='XIV' ; 
        elseif y> 1400 && y <= 1500
        cent ='XV'; 
        elseif y> 1500 && y <= 1600
        cent ='XVI' ; 
        elseif y> 1600 && y <= 1700
        cent ='XVII' ; 
        elseif y> 1700 && y <= 1800
        cent ='XVIII' ; 
        elseif y> 1800 && y <= 1900
        cent ='XIX'; 
        elseif y> 1900 && y <= 2000
        cent ='XX' ; 
        elseif y> 2000 && y <= 2100
        cent ='XXI' ; 
        elseif y> 2100 && y <= 2200
        cent ='XXII' ; 
        elseif y> 2200 && y <= 2300
        cent ='XXIII' ; 
        elseif y> 2300 && y <= 2400
        cent ='XXIV' ; 
        elseif y> 2400 && y <= 2500
        cent ='XXV' ; 
        elseif y> 2500 && y <= 2600
        cent ='XXVI' ; 
        elseif y> 2600 && y <= 2700
        cent ='XXVII' ; 
        elseif y> 2700 && y <= 2800
        cent ='XXVIII' ; 
        elseif y> 2800 && y <= 2900
        cent ='XXIX' ; 
        elseif y> 2900 && y <= 3000
        cent ='XXX'; 
        else cent =''.';
        end
else
        cent = ''; % Or whatever the fail return value should be
end
```

Comment: I'm posting the problem and my code , I've applied your suggestion but its still accepting a non integer  thanks

Comment: The statement that `isinteger` only accepts `uint8` is not true. Not only does MATLAB have more integer types than `uint8`, having an integer test function that only accepts integers would be totally useless.

Comment: i don't know why but when i used this :
 if ~isscalar(y) 
     cent = []; 
elseif y ~= floor(y)
    cent = [];
 it finally worked. but when i tried to combine both conditions on the same line , it didn't

Comment: What I meant to say is `isinteger` only returns true if the argument is of type (or its related types) `int`; perhaps my usage of "accepts" was misleading. Ref: http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isinteger.html

Comment: @OlubukolaOgunsola I've updated my answer, please verify with your changes.

Comment: @OlubukolaOgunsola: If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate you marking it as the 'Accepted Answer' as a motivation for future contributions.